# How can I force git to merge changes from branch to master that are "unchanged"

Tags: git, github, merge

I would like to force git to overwrite files in master from a branch, that it does not believe are changed.

```
Master Branch has file configA
Create branch from Master called BranchA which has file configA
Create Dev branch from Master called dev.
Make changes on dev, including changes to file configA
Merge changes from dev to master
```

Now I would like to overwrite the changes to configA on Master with file configA on BranchA (original file)
It will not merge configA back to the master, because it does not see configA on BranchA as a changed file.

I have used rm --cache to force git to "readd" the file configA to a commit on branchA, but it still ignores it.

Is there any command to force git to merge files from a branch, even if it does not believe they have been changed?

Thanks

Comment: Merge is of changes since a shared base -- and the file configA on the BranchA tip _hasn't_ been changed since the base that tip shares with Master's tip.  As Vampire points out, you just want that particular version, and the command you want is `git checkout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get its content and commit it?

```
git checkout Master
git checkout BranchA -- configA
git commit -m "whatever"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is more than one file. I am not familiar with the "-- filename" after git checkout BranchA. Does that copy the file to the master branch?

Comment: @HamletHub: *branches* don't have files so much as *commits* have files. What `git checkout <commit> -- path` does is to extract the file `path` (or multiple files if that's a directory), into the index/staging-area, and on to the work-tree. Those files are now both in your work-tree and `git add`ed to the index/staging-area, where they will be in the next commit you make. Making the commit will move the current branch name to point to the new commit you just made so that they will be in the tip commit on the branch. This is the picky/correct version of "yes, that puts them in the branch" :)